# Passing value from constructor to private integer within class

Tags: java, c++, constructor

I have experience working in Java but have recently started doing work in C++, I'm having a little trouble understanding how things are stored in memory in the latter. In java, the following is valid:

```
class Class {
    int myInt;

    public Class(int myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }
}
```

So I have an integer within the class, I give it a value when the object is created. I want to replicate this in C++:

```
class Class {
        int myInt;
    public:
        Class (int myInt) {
            // What goes here?
        }
};
```

This however doesn't work. If I name the variable being passed into the constructor something other than `myInt`, I can simply state `myInt = differentName`. But suppose like in the Java, I want both the variable passed to the constructor and the name of the variable to be the same? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

- Using an [Initializer list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

  ```
  class Class {
          int myInt;
      public:
          Class (int myInt) : myInt(myInt)
          {
          }
  };
  ```
- What you were intentionally looking for:

  ```
  class Class {
          int myInt;
      public:
          Class (int myInt)
          {
              Class::myInt = myInt;
          }
  };
  ```

But the first one is preferred.

Comment: I don't think OP was intentionally looking for the second variant. They just didn't know the way to initialize a data member in a C++ constructor yet.

Comment: @juanchopanza: He was looking for a `this.myInt = myInt;` equivalent. If you create a setter for this, you can't use initializer lists.

Comment: Not so sure. As I said, they didn't know how to initialize something in C++. They are just showing how to do something similar in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the constructor initialization list:

```
class Class {
        int myInt;
    public:
        Class (int myInt) : myInt(myInt) 
        {
          // by the time you get here, myInt is already initialized.
          // You can assign a value to it or modify it otherwise, 
          // but you cannot initialize something more than once.
        }
};
```

That the only way to explicitly *initialize* a data member in a constructor. Once you're in the body of the constructor, all data members have been initialized.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the initializer syntax, `this` is also available in C++. You would use it as `this->myInt` because `this` is a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

"this" is a pointer in C++. So it'll be

```
this->myInt = myInt;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the way to achieve the same in c++
    this->myInt = myInt;